# "If it is not" or "if it would not be" in context

Tags: grammar

Tell me please which one it is correct to use in the following context: *if it is not* or *if it would be not*?

> Wouldn't it be better just go home? **If it wouldn't**/**if it is not**, then what else could we do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of your suggestions are the most natural choice (and your first sentence is missing a "to").

> - Wouldn't it be better **to** just go home? (or "... just **to** go home?")
> - **If not,** then what else could we do?

Of your two suggestions, "If it wouldn't ..." is the only viable option. The present tense in "if it is not" clashes with the subjunctive in "wouldn't it."